# Ghostscript bold font

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

I'm using ghostscript to make jpeg images from PDF. It works good exept bold fonts in PDF document. The bolded text do not showing in images. Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly your PDF document does not contain the required fonts and GS is substituting for the missing fonts, and not using a bold version. OTOH perhaps the resolution you are rendering to is so low that there is no perceptible difference between bold and regular fonts.

Without an example file to inspect, and a sample command line, its really not possible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! It is really was that PDF document doesn't contain the required fonts.